# css/scss: is there a way to clean this up and make it dryer?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I have a class `content` and `isActive`.  Do I have to "include" the mixin twice like below so that it would apply when I have an element like `<div class="content">` and `<div class="content isActive">`

```
 .content {
    padding: 0 40px;

    &.isActive {
      padding: 20px 40px;
      background: black;
      color: $color-white;
      border-right: none;

      .meta {
        border-bottom: none;
      }

      @include tablet-vertical-down {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    }

    @include tablet-vertical-down {
      border: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You would be better asking this at CodeReview.SE but check their guidelines first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&` to refer to the current selector and combine it with `&.isActive`.

```
.content {
    padding: 0 40px;

    &.isActive {
      padding: 20px 40px;
      background: black;
      color: $color-white;
      border-right: none;

      .meta {
        border-bottom: none;
      }
    }

    &, &.isActive {
      @include tablet-vertical-down {
        border: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    }
  }
```